# SQL Server stored procedure random failure

Tags: exception, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_cache_remove]  
 @Key NVARCHAR(450)  
AS  
BEGIN  

 --Clean up first  
 DELETE FROM Cache WHERE Expire <= GETUTCDATE()  

 DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(MAX)  
 SELECT TOP 1 @Result = Value   
 FROM Cache  
 WHERE [Key] = @Key AND  
   Expire > GETUTCDATE()  

 DELETE FROM Cache WHERE [Key] = @Key  

 SELECT @Result  

END
```

This one fails randomly. When I commented out the first line (`DELETE FROM...`), it works fine. This only happens on a production server, so getting more error details is not possible. Can anybody identify any possible problem here?

**Edit**: There are other stored procedures for add, get, etc. Could there be a deadlock or something?

Comment: define "fails".  The only bug I can see is "TOP" without ORDER BY

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @LoztInSpace: I have a try/catch block which catches an SqlException, and that shows it fails. TOP shouldn't be a problem as I have a WHERE clause and [Key] is primary key.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: Since the exception caught just has a generic message, I can't find the actual error message from SQL server.

Comment: Is there nothing in the Message property of the Exception?

Answer (score 1):

you retrieve nothing at all try initaliazed the @Result

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_cache_remove]  
 @Key NVARCHAR(450)  
AS  
BEGIN  

 --Clean up first  
 DELETE FROM Cache WHERE Expire <= GETUTCDATE()  

 DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    set @Result = ''        -- <---- Initialized variable
 SELECT TOP 1 @Result = Value   
 FROM Cache  
 WHERE [Key] = @Key AND  
   Expire > GETUTCDATE()  

 DELETE FROM Cache WHERE [Key] = @Key  

 SELECT @Result  

END
```

Comment: If I just call the stored procedure for testing, it works fine even without the Result being initialized as you have shown. So I don't think it's needed.

Comment: Where did you call the stored procedure when it throws exception?

Comment: All these stored procedures (add, get, remove, etc) are called pretty much random. Where they are called from, from different parts of the application.